# My query inside loop taking too long to proccess

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have a lumen apps using eloquent, i have a query inside loop that taking too long to execute. This is the code :

```
$DtPayments = Payments::whereIn('payment_status', [PYG_STATUS_NEW, PYG_STATUS_PAYED, PYG_STATUS_RESUBMIT, PYG_STATUS_SENT])
    ->whereNull('payment_care_status')
    ->whereNotNull('payment_voucherno')
    ->select('payment_id', 'payment_voucherno', 'payment_installment', 'payment_amount')
    ->orderBy('payment_id', 'ASC')
    ->chunk(200, function ($DtPayments) use ($Logger, $total_data, $total_success, $total_fail){
        foreach($DtPayments as $payment){
            $Logger->write_log('info', 'Check payment ID ' . $payment->payment_id);

            $statementGetInfopSLVoucher = "Select pSL.Doc_No, Max(pSL.Voucher) as Voucher, "
                    . "Sum(dbo.fn_SL_Payment_Nominal(pSL.Nominal_OC, pVoucher.SL_Cat, pVoucher.DebtorF, DebtorF)) as Nominal_OC "
                    . "from pSL, pVoucher Where pSL.PaymentF=1 and pVoucher.Voucher=pSL.Voucher "
                    . "and psl.Doc_No in (SELECT VOUCHER FROM AdmLink WHERE DOCNO LIKE '{$payment->payment_source_number}%' AND TYPE IN ('DI','IC')) Group By pSL.Doc_No";

            try {
                $getInfoPembayaran = DB::connection('default')->select(DB::connection('default')->raw($statementGetInfopSLVoucher));

            ...
            }
```

I try change the $DtPayments to this :

```
$DtPayments = Payments::whereIn('payment_id', [68670,68671,68672,69324,69329,69330,69332,69333,69335,69334])
    ->get();
```

The query inside loop run quickly. So i think the problem is with $DtPayments. Is there any best practice to tweak $DtPayments?

Thanks before

Comment: For each result you're doing another query with tables and subtables. Even if each individual query runs quickly if you have thousands of results the query time plus the round-trip time it will add up

Comment: so with this condition, is there any method that can speed up the proccess?

Comment: I don't know but I'm retagging this as an SQL question. However you might want to analyse the current queries first and see if there's a way to either make them into one or do less queries for each result chunk. Otherwise I think this is a bit too broad a question